# What is the least times to make all the number $1$ to $0$?

Tags: combinatorics

Given an $n$-bit binary number of all $1$, you can turn $k$ bits every time ($k < n$).

What is the least times to make the number all $0$?

> In some cases, there is no solution. like $n=3, k=2$.
>
> In some trivial cases, like $k \mid n$, the solution is $\frac{n}{k}$.
>
> An example: $n=10,k=4$. the number is $1111111111$.
>
> 1. the number will be $0000111111$.
> 2. it will be $0001000111$.
> 3. it will be $0000000000$. finished.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337810/minimal-number-of-steps-needed-to-turn-all-binary-bits-to-one-state

Comment: Do you have to flip exactly $k$ bits?  Do they have to be contiguous?  Why in your last example do you flip four bits at a time when $k=3$?

Comment: @RossMillikan sorry, the example is $k=4$, I will fix it. sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is odd and $k$ is even, no solution exists as each move leaves the parity unchanged. So assume $n$ is even or $k$ is odd.

If $2k<n$, two consecutive moves can together flip any even number up to $2k$ bits, depending on the overlap between the two moves. Hence if $2k<n$ and there exists $r$ with $0<n-rk\le 2k$ and $2\mid n-rk$, we can solve the problem in $r+2$ moves. We can take $r=\lfloor\frac {n-1}k\rfloor-1$, except when this makes $n-rk$ odd, in which case we take $r=\lfloor \frac {n-1}k\rfloor$. If $k$ is odd, this is automatically optimal as parity tells us that anything better than $r+2$ moves must use $r$ moves or less, but $rk<n$. But this is also the case when $k$ (and hence also $n$) is even: In this case, we have $r=\lfloor \frac{ n-1}k\rfloor-1$, hence after $r+1$ moves cannot flip more than $k(r+1)\le n-1$ bits.

If $2k>n>k$, two consecutive moves can be combined to flip any even number up to $2(n-k)$ bits, again depending on their overlap. Then if additionally $n\equiv k\pmod 2$, three moves suffice because the $n-k$ bits left after one move can be dealt with in two moves. If $n\not\equiv k\pmod 2$, then by the first paragraph, we assume $n$ is even and $k$ is odd. By parity, the total number of moves must be even. Combining every two consecutive moves, we get a sequence of flips of an arbitrary even number up to $2(n-k)$ each. We conclude that $2\lceil\frac{n}{2(n-k)}\rceil$ moves are possible and are optimal.

Comment: some parts I can not understand. why assume $n$ is even and $k$ is odd? $(n,k)=(11,3)$ has solution. And "except when this makes $n-rk$ odd"? but before that,we let $2 \mid n-rk$.